# Is there any way to implements lazy evaluation in .filter() .map() .forEach and so on by Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

In my opinion, if I have multiple filter() call. The set will be iterate multiple times. I want the code like this:

Generate full inline the best.

```
set.filter{a>10}.filter{a<20}.forEach{doSomething()}
```

```
for(e in set){ // Only iterate the set one time.
    if(e.a>10){
        if(e.a<20)
            doSomething()
    }
}
```

Comment: Your second code example *does* only iterate one time.

Comment: https://medium.com/@elye.project/kotlin-slow-list-and-lazy-sequence-61691fc974c5

Comment: https://blog.kotlin-academy.com/effective-kotlin-use-sequence-for-bigger-collections-with-more-than-one-processing-step-649a15bb4bf

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yeah, I want kotlin generate code like this.(The second example.) Thank you.

Comment: Read the two articles I linked.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I read the two articles. It looks the Sequece mothod not 'inlined'. I wish there a way to generate inline code for better performance. Like my example, the inline all lambda in one function. Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you measured the performance of your code and identified it to be an actual problem?

Comment: @RobertHarvey No, just my Obsessive-compulsive disorder(OCD). :) Thank you.

Comment: Not sure whether I got the question correctly. set.filter{ a in 10..20 }.forEach{ doSomething() } is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use range operator to do that.

```
set.filter{ it.a in 10..20 }.forEach{ doSomething() }
```

or if you have any complicated condition to be done, then you can create a method which returns boolean.

```
set.filter{ isInRange(it.a, x, y) }.forEach{ doSomething() } 

// create a function
fun isInRange(value: Int, x: Int, y: Int) = value in x..y // both inclusive
```

Comment: This only an simple example. Thank you.

Comment: sure. so what exactly you are looking for. can you please elaborate. I could try to answer. @cpdyj

Comment: The previous answer say Sequence. But it looks isn't inlined. So, are there any way to generate code like sequence inline? Thank you. I think inline will bring better performance. Thank you.

Comment: I don't found any way to generate code inline. It looks because kotlin can't generate true inline class?(I know kotlin has inline class, but there're many limit.) Sorry, my English is poor. Thx